# Django get_absolute_url from cms page

Tags: django, django-cms

I want to access to the url from a cms page

```
from cms.models import Page

page = Page.objects.published()[3]   #clinics page
print page.get_absolute_url()
```

But it shows this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /en/clinics/ 
The included urlconf urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

Clinics page works (admin + frontend), the problem is when I try to call `get_absolute_url()`

part of urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

clinics/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from clinics import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.clinic_list, name='clinic_list'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do it and it works. Calling the `reverse` of the `clinic_list` route directly. I think the way of passing through the cms page is not necessary.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

print reverse('clinic_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
page = Page.objects.published()[3]
```

This won't work, as `published` is a `BooleanField` from the model `Page`.

What you want to do is:

```
page = page.objects.get(pk=3) # At least if this pk is 3, check with your installation.
page.get_absolute_url()
```

Comment: Could you update your question with your urls.py? Could it be you used an app on this page and haven't restarted your server?